# SAFE Multisig: API for Creation of proposed transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe

Do you know if there's something similar to OpenZeppelin Defender v1 proposals (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/v1/admin) for Safe Multisigs?

OZ Defender proposals are proposed calls to make on smart contracts (individual or batches) that can be created by non-signer users and then they are presented to the signers to review and sign.

The proposals can be created from the UI or through an API interface. I'm more interested in the latest since we use this integrated with GitHub actions.

This is possible or something similar to this is possible? AFAIK, the only way to create a "proposal" in Safe is if one of the members creates (from the UI, also signing) the proposed transaction.

P.S.: OZ defender proposals are great, but they have a few issues and OZ is going in another direction with the product.

Answer (score 0):

as of now Safes don't natively support that feature, however you could easily develop a [custom module](https://docs.safe.global/smart-account-modules) for proposal creation, that could interact with a [Safe App](https://docs.safe.global/apps-sdk-overview) (or any other web application) to create proposals via a UI or via an API.

By using modules, you can override some of the checks in place when using a Safe from the official Wallet UI, and can directly execute functions at the smart contract level.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis